# Preventing unnecessary re-renders of table rows / children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, hover, state

Suppose there's a table that needs to keep some state, for example, knowing the last element that was hovered over. To do so, we'd need a `onMouseOver` event on a child element like this:

`<tr onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}></tr>`

and then the component containing the table would re-render all the children after `setState({lastHovered: e.target})` (something along those lines)

If the goal of hover is to make changes to just one row (let's say show/hide something without using CSS) is there a way to keep this state at a higher level than the row and only render changes in the `<tr>`s that are affected by the hover?

As an example, let's say there's a delay on hovering in or out of the table. When hovering in, children should show a tooltip, but only if hovered directly over. The table/parent need to maintain some state to keep track of this **but is there a way to not have to re-render the entire list of children**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Functional Components

Wrap all the `tr` elements inside a `React.memo` ([read](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)) to only listen for changes to its internal props. Also, place the `onMouseOver` event on the table itself and not every child immediate element, then check which child element is in "focus" (i.e., `event.target`).

Inside table component:

```
const [lastHovered, setLastHovered] = useState(null);
const [trProps, setTrProps] = useState(null);

return (
  <table onMouseOver={event => setLastHovered(event.target) /* Also check if 'TR' type */ }> 
    <TableRows someData={trProps} />
  </table>
)
```

Table rows component:

```
const TableRows = React.memo( ({someData}) => /* Triggers update only if 'someData' changes */
      <> { someData.map( data => <tr>{data}</tr> ) } </>
    )
```

Note: The above code isn't tested; written to demonstrate a possible solution.

### For Class Components

If you're using class components, then create a custom TableRow element and add `shouldComponentUpdate()` ([read](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)) to control rerenders, or use `PureComponents` ([read](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)) instead.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I need. A little twist... suppose what I need is to display that tooltip after a certain period of time. How the hover changes are actuated has no effect on where the state is stored (table), am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: If visual effects on the table rows are being handled by CSS, then hover changes shouldn't affect where the state is stored. However, if the table row component relies on JS `mouseOver` event to trigger the hover effect, then we'd have to rethink a solution. The `PureComponents` approach would be the better option though.

Comment: Would you mind taking a peek at my previous question here then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70446284/conditionally-displaying-react-components-with-hover-and-timeouts

Memoization is still an excellent idea to explore though

Comment: @McDerp I posted a possible solution to that issue.